# How to display FloatingActionButton above listview?

Tags: android, listview

I want to display the FloatingActionButton above my listview. I am using this code in my activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

            />
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"
            />






        <!-- List view goes here-->

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
            android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>


    </LinearLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It looks like:
[image]

I want it to appear on the top of the list view till the list view is loaded completely.
Also, how can I get rotating refresh icon? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button over a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871346/button-over-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to group the ListView and the FloatingActionButton in a RelativeLayout.

A better solution is to change their parent layout (Which is LinearLayout in your case) to a RelativeLayout. But you will need to use a combination of `layout_alignParentTop` `layout_above` and `layout_below` in the children to achieve the order you want.

Comment: what about rotating buttons?

Comment: @learner So the button is simply to indicate the ListView is refreshing?

Comment: I want a rotating circle instead of refresh icon, and also can you edit your answer a little with code?

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout to display fab above ListView.

Here's nice library with many features and animations, including rotation:

https://github.com/shell-software/fab

Comment: Can you please provide me some code? Link to other sites is not considered to be good at SO.

Comment: So be a bit more specific, provide additional details, what exactly rotation do you want to implement?

Comment: I do not understand why it was voted down. I struggled with a problem that my fab was not displayed on top of my listview, for days, until I saw this post, and changed my layout from linear to relative. Thanks @anton

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting padding below the list(I think your recyclerview). The height of the padding must be as that of the fab icon. 
In Flutter this solution work perfectly..